# How to send unclickable links in email

Tags: html, email, hyperlink

I want to send the url as plain text in the emails sent through the asp.net application.Now it is automatically converting to hyperlinks. Please help.

Comment: The email client is probably automatically doing that. If you add a space after the "." it will not convert them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One technique I know of is to have

```
www.url.<img src="" width="0" height="0">com
```

That way it won't be parsed as a web address whilst not impacting on the layout. If you're having issues with the `<img>` receiving some sort of styling then it may be better to use:

```
www.url.&#65279;com
```

Where `&#65279;` is a zero width non-breaking space.

Comment: +1 for a good find (although it's a bit sneaky). Should work as long as nothing overrides the img's width

Comment: @Grahamvs Possibly less sneaky alternative added.

Comment: Nice alternative... I would suggest testing this with a few different email clients to ensure they don't ignore the `&#65279;`

Comment: I've observed that some email providers will add an 'object replacement symbol'  character.  So I don't the image trick is a robust solution. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EF%BF%BC

Comment: Edit: The 'object replacement symbol' is inserted when the text is copied.  My use case was to make the url easier to copy by making it unclickable.  So the image trick doesn't work for this.